# Run the chef-client as non root user

Tags: chef-infra

I want to run the chef-client as a test user in my linux machine. For that, I add cache path in the client.rb file which is from /etc/chef/client.rb.

```
cache_path "~/.chef/cache"
```

Then I run the chef-client command from test user(non-root user).It shows error?

```
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client
```

How to setup the cache-path? Is is necessary to move the client.rb,chef-validator.pem, client.pem, first-boot.json under test user?

Comment: added the cache_path "/home/test/cache". This also shows same error and It says I can read which you told me to sign requests

Answer (score 3):

First of all, chef is intended to be run as root. A lot of resources assume they're run as root, and need it. They **will fail** if **not** running as root.

For your error specifically, your test user has no right to write a file in `/etc/chef` (default location) and it need to write the `client.pem` node certificate.

Some ideas:

1. Give rights on `/etc/chef` to your test user
2. use `sudo` to run chef client with a test user (need an entry in sudoers file)
3. Modify the `client.rb` file to point `client_key` to your test user home directory
4. Do a first run of chef as root so it can write it's node certificate, then it won't have to write again in `/etc/chef`

Comment: Is it necessary to write the client.rb file in this location /etc/chef . Shall I create a folder 'chef' in /home/test location and put the files there(client.pem, client.rb, validation.pem)

Comment: Hey I gave chmod 777 permission to all files which is present inside the folder /etc/chef/. Now chef-client run from the test user. Is it the right way? I didnt add the cache_path in my client.rb file?Then How it works. I checked the permission of the folder /var/chef/cache Its all are '755' mode