# Can't run Chef as root

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I've recently returned to Linux after a 2-year hiatus.  I'm trying to 
[learn Chef](https://learn.chef.io/learn-the-basics/rhel/configure-a-package-and-service/) in order to automate some application deployments. In the Chef tutorial, it states that `sudo` is required to run a command that installs a package, which makes sense.

**webserver.rb**

```
package 'httpd'
```

**shell command**

```
sudo chef-apply webserver.rb
```

Tutorial excerpt:

> `sudo` is required because this command installs a package and therefore must be run with root privileges. If you're running as root on your own machine, you can omit `sudo` from the command.

I googled the issue I was having and found a ["solution" that didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852242/to-specs-could-not-find-chef-0-amongst-gemloaderror), along with an [SO question that stated you shouldn't run Chef as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280211/run-the-chef-client-as-non-root-user).  I'm not sure if I buy it.

> First of all, chef is not intended to be run as root. A lot of resources assume they're run as root, and need it. They will fail if not running as root.

He also states that you should use `sudo`, which conflicts with his previous statement.

> use sudo to run chef client with a test user (need an entry in sudoers file)

I think that he meant to say that you shouldn't run Chef as root 100% of the time.  I am failing to run Chef as root, which seems to be the opposite of what the OP was trying to solve.

**The error I am getting**

```
/opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'chef' (>= 0) among 13 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
        from /opt/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
        from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/chef-apply:22:in `<main>'
        from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /opt/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

If the tutorial says that you CAN run Chef as root, and root is required to execute certain recipes, then I would think that Chef should run as root in certain cases.

My biggest question is how do I fix this error and run Chef as root?  It runs fine as any other user, but fails when I try to `sudo`.

Comment: Are you able to run Chef as non-root user? It seems like failing to find your Chef gem.

Comment: I can run Chef as non-root user.  I thought that I was missing the Chef gem, so I installed that and then ran `rvm reset` and everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `rvm reset` worked after all.

So the "solution" post that I mocked earlier was actually the solution I was looking for.  Karma.

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT INSTALL CHEF BY GEM.** (plenty of good reason too long to explain, but trust me, use omnibus package)

What happened here is that your rvm has override the path search order and the ruby call, thus the chef launcher was searching in the rvm path and not in the embedded ruby chef path. Calling `rvm reset` fix the problem by removing the override/path addition.

---

For the 'to be or not to be root' part, my answer on the question you linked had a typo. The **not** was forget after a rewording, (the remaining of the sentence made clear root is needed I hope). Thanks for the head up anyway.

Chef is mean to be run as `root`, but it's highly discouraged to connect remotely to a machine as `root`.

So you should use `sudo` to launch `chef-client` with `root` permissions 100% of time. Chef will fail on some operations if run as a normal user as it is intended to manage a whole system.

Note: I say 'should' and not 'must' as someone can probably find an edge case where it's advisable to run chef in a limited environment, but I really think it's an edge case and maybe chef is not the correct tool in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; it provided clarity.

Comment: you're welcome. Was too long for a comment on your answer ;)

Comment: I have an opposite experience. Installing it as an omnibus package provided some very annoying errors and problems. Now I have Chef installed with gems and it works perfectly. I should say also I do not use rvm too.

Comment: @Draco gem install is unsupported, use at your own risk. Gem install was OK in chef version before 11.