# Unable to run Chef cron recipe as non-root user

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm standing up a new environment where Chef nodes will have to run `chef-client` as non-root user.  (I have created a `chef-user` with `rwx` privileges to `/etc/chef/`, and the `client.rb` points to the correct client key per [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280211/run-the-chef-client-as-non-root-user).)  Below is my test recipe:

```
cron "clientrun2m" do
  minute '*/2'
  command "/bin/chef-client"
  action :create
  user "chef-user"
end
```

When I am logged into the target node as `chef-user`, I try (unsuccessfully) to execute `chef-client` (not with sudo) and get the following info.  It seems like the error is with the converging of resources and not related to user permissions or private keys.  (I'm able to run this cookbook, minus the `user "chef-user"` line, and under sudo'd while on another node with no problem.)  Any ideas why this recipe is not working for my non-root user?

```
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 2 resources
Recipe: cron-delvalidate2m::2min_cu
  * cron[clientrun2m] action create[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] INFO: Processing cron[clientrun2m] action create (cron-delvalidate2m::2min_cu line 7)


    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'cron[clientrun2m]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::Cron
    ----------------------
    Error updating state of clientrun2m, exit: 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /home/chef-user/.chef/cache/cookbooks/cron-delvalidate2m/recipes/2min_cu.rb

      7: cron "clientrun2m" do
      8:   minute '*/2'
      9:   command "/bin/chef-client"
     10:   action :create
     11:   user "chef-user"
     12: end
     13:

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /home/chef-user/.chef/cache/cookbooks/cron-delvalidate2m/recipes/2min_cu.rb:7:in `from_file'

    cron("clientrun2m") do
      action [:create]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      minute "*/2"
      hour "*"
      day "*"
      month "*"
      weekday "*"
      command "/bin/chef-client"
      user "chef-user"
      declared_type :cron
      cookbook_name "cron-delvalidate2m"
      recipe_name "2min_cu"
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
    x86_64-linux

[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception

Running handlers:
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: 92566ddb-e078-44b2-b862-be34da4a18b4)
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] INFO: Unable to access cache at /var/chef. Switching cache to /home/chef-user/.chef
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] INFO: Unable to access cache at /var/chef. Switching cache to /home/chef-user/.chef
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/chef-user/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] ERROR: cron[clientrun2m] (cron-delvalidate2m::2min_cu line 7) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Cron: Error updating state of clientrun2m, exit: 1
[2016-11-07T11:53:22-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

And the cited stacktrace.out file mentioned in third to last line above.

```
[chef-user@ip-10-0-0-230 ~]$ cat /home/chef-user/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Generated at 2016-11-07 11:53:22 -0500
Chef::Exceptions::Cron: cron[clientrun2m] (cron-delvalidate2m::2min_cu line 7) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Cron: Error updating state of clientrun2m, exit: 1
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:231:in `write_crontab'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:157:in `block in action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider.rb:176:in `converge_by'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:156:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource.rb:603:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:69:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:114:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:103:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:96:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:669:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:664:in `catch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:664:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:703:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:283:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:302:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:290:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:290:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:255:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:243:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:464:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:451:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:434:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/chef-client:54:in `load'
/bin/chef-client:54:in `<main>'

>>>> Caused by Chef::Exceptions::Cron: Error updating state of clientrun2m, exit: 1
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:231:in `write_crontab'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:157:in `block in action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider.rb:176:in `converge_by'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:156:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource.rb:603:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:69:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:114:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:103:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/runner.rb:96:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:669:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:664:in `catch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:664:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:703:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/client.rb:283:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:302:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:290:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:290:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:255:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:243:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:464:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:451:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application/client.rb:434:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.15.19/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/chef-client:54:in `load'
```

Comment: As stated in the log (the two FATAL level lines), the stacktrace would be great to help finding the root cause of the failure. Seems like a bug when replacing the crontab (or writing at the wrong place, assuming root) but help us helping you by providing it and not having to reproduce it.

Comment: Relevant code should be [here](read_crontab) Try the commands `crontab -l -u chef-user` as `chef-user` and see if it yeld an error.

Comment: @Tensibai, apologies I missed that stacktrace file when I first read output.  Now attached.  When I run your `crontab`, I get "must be privileged to use -u", looks like this is an [outstanding issue or point of contention][1] with Chef's  cron provider  [1]: https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/2491

Comment: Sorry, I should have been rude if you feel the need to apologize, you did hit a 'bug'. And yes you did find the root cause, as it's using -u to setup the crontab it should be root (Chef is written mostly with this assumption) but I think the cron resource could be fixed for this case. I'll see what I can do tomorow. Can you give more details on your node (distribution,  selinux activated or nor, or any other hardening in place) ?

Comment: @Tensibai, no worries.  Here's my info: chef-client:v12.15.19; chef-server-core:v12.9.1.el7x86; RHEL:7.2 (all boxes); selinux-policy(epoch: 0;version: 3.13.1) I found from Node's attributes on server, not sure if this is what you're looking for.  Otherwise let me know if more needed.

Answer (score 0):

I did find [this open issue](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/2491).  Chef's `cron` provider does not interface correctly with the node's `crontab` command when a non-root user is specified.  A fix might be in the backlog.

For my own uses, I need to have my nodes run with non-root users.  I was able to hack some custom recipes to replicate the functionality that I needed.

**Recipe1: Add chef-client to the crontab**

```
# Removes any crontab job of 'chef-client' before inserting the new 'chef-client' crontab job (for every 2 mins)
execute "clientrun2m" do
  command "crontab -l | grep -v chef-client | crontab - && (crontab -l; echo \"*/2 * * * * /bin/chef-client\") | crontab -"
  action :run
end

# Delete the validation.pem for security reasons
file "/etc/chef/validation.pem" do
  action :delete
end
```

**Remove chef-client from the crontab**

```
# Removes any crontab job of 'chef-client'
execute "clientrun2m" do
  command "crontab -l | grep -v chef-client | crontab -"
  action :run
end

# Delete the validation.pem for security reasons
file "/etc/chef/validation.pem" do
  action :delete
end
```

Comment: This answer is correct as a workaround, but just for the sake of stating it: this is not super likely to be fixed unless someone updates the patch for us. In general we only _really_ support (as in put a lot of resources toward improving) running as non-root users for workstation management and cron just doesn't come up much in that use case. Sorry for the difficulty, I would recommend working out if you can switch to running Chef as root instead.

Comment: @coderanger, sorry for nitpicking, but for clarity: "... in general [Chef?] only really support running as [root?] for workstation management..."?  Otherwise could you clarify your 2nd sentence, maybe specific to cron?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, we == the Chef maintainers. The primary non-root use case is for Mac and Windows workstation management and for that we both ensure things work smoothly and have enough users to tell us when things break. Doing unix-y server-y stuff in Chef as a non-root user is just a very niche area and so isn't as well tested and doesn't get much dev time.